# install4j - Select installed components during uninstall

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to allow the user to select which components they wish to uninstall during the uninstall?

If not, what's a possible solution to facilitate this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first question: have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: As far as I could find, nothing makes mention of being able to select which components to uninstall, it just uninstalls what you've already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 5, there is no concept of a "maintenance installer" in install4j. The uninstaller removes everything that was installed by the installer.

Comment: Ah, I figured as much.